# OS X: Port forwarding a VPN to LAN

Tags: networking, macos, vpn, port-forwarding

I have a Mac Mini running OS X 10.6.8. I use this old buddy as a Media Server. On this Mac Mini I have a VPN connection which connects me to a server running a service at port 80 and 4747. I want to forward these services to my LAN.

Mac Mini network:

```
en1   -- WLAN -- 192.168.0.23 -- my LAN at home
tun0  -- VPN  -- 192.168.125.30
```

On the Mac Mini I can access the server over tun0 at IP 192.168.125.1.

I want to make the port 192.168.123.1:80 and 192.168.125.1:4747 available to the network connected at en1.

It would be great if I could reach the server at the Mac Mini's address via 192.168.0.23:80 and the Mac Mini will forward or nat this to 192.168.125.1:80 (tun0).

Background is: I don't want to connect every device to the VPN in order to access the services provided by 192.168.125.1.

Can anyone give me some hints on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your server needs to be connected to both networks or "Subnets"

Plug in a network cable from each network into your server,

In the network settings for the 192.168.0.23 network, delete it's default gateway(assuming it is statically assigned)
http://www.macworld.com/article/2027960/configuring-your-macs-network-settings.html

All this does is it allows you to access it internally, or through your vpn, but it does not access the outside world or interfere with the other network.

This way you should be able to reach the server via both IP addresses

Comment: Well I cant do that. I connect to VPN over Internet...

Comment: Where is the server you are connecting to located?